# Sync shell script fails on ls when file not found

Tags: shell, zsh

I have written a shell script to sync my dotfiles repository to my home directory. This was working fine in Cygwin (zsh), but I've just migrated to Linux (zsh on Xubuntu 12.10) and it's failing.

The script makes a list of the relevant dotfiles in the repo then, before creating symlinks, it archives any clashes. The archiving routine is as follows:

```
for i in $dotFiles; do
  toArchive=$toArchive $(ls -d $i)
done
```

This fails when any item in `$dotfiles` doesn't exist; `ls` returns `No such file or directory` and the script terminates.

Would redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` resolve this? i.e.:

```
for i in $dotFiles; do
  toArchive=$toArchive $(ls -d $i 2>/dev/null)
done
```

...or is there a better solution?

(My script is [here](https://github.com/Xophmeister/dotfiles/blob/master/sync), for sake of completeness.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the suggestions posted here individually and wrapped them into a whole solution. I don't know what it was that was breaking the logic in my script, but if I were to guess, I'd say it was probably parsing the results of `ls` and/or using a spaced string, rather than a zsh array... Anyway, the working script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/zsh

# Break on first error and unset variables
set -e
set -u

# Gather dotfiles
repoDir=$(pwd)

cd $repoDir/public
publicDotfiles=(.*)
cd $repoDir/private
privateDotfiles=(.*)

# Determine clashes, to backup
typeset -a toBackup
for file in $publicDotfiles $privateDotfiles; do
  dotFile=$HOME/$file
  if [[ -e $dotFile ]] toBackup=($toBackup $dotFile)
done

if [[ "$toBackup" != "" ]]; then
  backupFile=$HOME/dotfiles.$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz
  tar czPf $backupFile $toBackup --remove-files
fi

# Create symlinks
for i in $publicDotfiles; do
  ln -s $repoDir/public/$i $HOME/$i
done

for i in $privateDotfiles; do
  ln -s $repoDir/private/$i $HOME/$i
done
```

While I was at it, I made it slightly more robust:

- There are two classes of dotfiles, public and private. The private directory is for things like `.gnupg`, etc. Its contents are ignored by Git, so they never get pushed out.
- Providing the script is run from its own directory, the project folder can be anywhere and then the script works out absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

The worst thing with a shell-script is making it work. The second worst is maintaining (having t figure out in six months time what each line/option did). With that in mind, I suggest you to just add an existence check:

```
for i in $dotFiles; do
  if [[ -e $i ]]; then
      toArchive=$toArchive $(ls -d $i)
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly why your script terminated on the first error (`set -e` in effect? Running as part of a Makefile rule?), but ignoring the non-zero status of any command can be achieved by running

```
 cmd || :
```

(read: *command or true*). Does

```
  $(ls -d $i || :)
```

do the trick?

PS: I looked at your script. In fact, `set -e` is in effect. You might want to remove it completely or selectively turn it on only for specific regions of your script (`set +e` undoes the effect of `set -e`).

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try this when I'm home and let you know!... The `set` flags were recommended to me when I posted my script to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10485/shell-script-to-sync-dotfiles-repository). I kept them as it seemed sensible, especially given my [lack of] shell scripting experience!

Comment: ...I made the change you suggested and it still didn't work: The script now just iterates through all the missing dotfiles, complaining that they don't exist, but without failing. What happens now is, when a match is found, it errors at the same point with `./sync: .dotfile: not found`.

Comment: Well, error messages are still being generated. I think you have a logic problem in your script. Why does $dotfiles contain nonexistent files at all? And if it needs to, why run commands that error for nonexistent files? In that case it is better to test for existence first and skip operations on non-existent files.

Answer (score 1):

Zsh, unlike other shells, does not execute a command when the file name pattern does not match anything. Meaning an `echo hello *` in an empty directory will not actually print `hello *` on the screen. Instead, zsh will print said error message and `echo` will not get executed.

You can switch that on and off with one of those funky options called `NOMATCH` which is active by default. Read zsh's info pages on how it works, please. And [chapter 2 in the zsh FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#l9) also explains about this.

However, if I interpret your intention correctly then you have a list of file names that may or may not actually exist, and you only want to include a file name in the backup if it exists. If that is the case then here is a better version using arrays and file existence tests:

```
typeset -a files_to_backup
for file in $dotFiles ; do
  if [[ -f $file ]] files_to_backup=($files_to_backup $file)
done
```

This also uses zsh's short conditional syntax for the `if`, in case you're wondering.

Comment: Looks like the FAQ is back up; I'll read it. As you're using zsh builtins and syntax, presumably I'll also need to change the shebang line from sh (dash, in Ubuntu) to zsh... Anyway, I will try this. Thank you :)

Comment: I've fixed the link to the proper FAQ page. Yes, my intention was indeed to use zsh's capabilities fully, not portability across different shells. Arrays can be used in bash and zsh but not in dash, but they make life so much easier, especially when dealing with file names containing spaces.